# reading flashvars problem for swfobject

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, swfobject

I have a flash swf of 1.2mb.
am embeding it with swfobject using dynamic embeding .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {};

flashvars.campaignid = "12345678890";
var params = {};
params.allowscriptaccess = "always";
var attributes = {};
swfobject.embedSWF("soccer.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "550", "400", "10.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

am tring to read campaignid inside my document class ...

the code is like

```
public function Main()
{    
    loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,update); 
    loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoadedMovie); 
}                 
private function update(e:ProgressEvent):void         
{
}

private function onLoadedMovie(e:Event)
{
    campId=this.root.loaderInfo.parameters["campaignid"]; 
}
```

when i alert the value i got null
when i use the same method in a small file it works..
can anyone help me?
regards

Comment: Does "when i alert the value" mean when you use `alert()` with javascript or `trace()` with actionscript. Also what does "when i use the same method in a small file it works" mean? what small file?

Comment: Alert is third party class to alert in flash. 
Small file means in case size , it's about 1.6 mb. But the thing is i made another file with 1.8 mb and the swf read  the param.

actually i got the answer. I just added variable in embed code like
swfobject.embedSWF("soccer.swf?campaignid=1234556")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer by adding variable in the embed code. like this

```
swfobject.embedSWF("soccer.swf?campaignid=1234556"", "myAlternativeContent", "550", "400", "10.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Adam Harte's answer is correct, I think the problem lies somewhere within your AS3 code, the following especially confused me:

```
public function Main() 
{     
    loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,update);  
    loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoadedMovie);  
}

private function update(e:ProgressEvent):void { } 

private function onLoadedMovie(e:Event) 
{ 
    campId=this.root.loaderInfo.parameters["campaignid"];  
}
```

I've created a simple(and working) example of how your code should look:

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>FlashVars</title>
    <meta name="language" content="en" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <script src="js/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = { campaignid: "12345678890" };
        var params = { menu: "false", scale: "noScale", allowFullscreen: "true", allowScriptAccess: "always", bgcolor: "", wmode: "direct" };
        var attributes = { id:"FlashVars" };
        swfobject.embedSWF("FlashVars.swf", "altContent", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { height:100%; overflow:hidden; }
        body { margin:0; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="altContent">
        <h1>FlashVars</h1>
        <p>Alternative content</p>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Main.as**(document class):

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            if (loaderInfo.parameters.campaignid)
            {
                var textField:TextField = new TextField();
                textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
                textField.text = loaderInfo.parameters.campaignid;
                addChild(textField);

            }// end if

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

The following is an image of the example beening run in a browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try getting the var after your Main class has been added to the stage. This will make sure everything is loaded and ready. Try something like this:

```
public function Main()
{
    if (stage) init();
    else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    var campId:String = this.root.loaderInfo.parameters["campaignid"];
    trace('campId', campId);
}
```

Comment: I have changed the embed code and it seems to be working .
swfobject.embedSWF("soccer.swf?campaignid=1234556",

I don't know the reason but i got the value inside my flash